# Target class within footer tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to append some HTML to the end of `div` within a `footer` tag like this:

```
<footer>
 <div class="menu-footer">
  <p>Stuff</p>
  <!-- want to insert HTML here -->
 </div>
</footer>
```

I'm not sure how to target the child class using regular JavaScript. I know I could use jQuery, but that's not available, so I'm trying the vanilla JS way. I know I can use `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementsByTagName`, but I'm not sure how to chain them together to use `insertAdjacentHTML`. For example:

```
function loadThing() {
var footer = document.querySelector('footer .menu-footer');
footer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>Stuff to add</p>');
}

window.onload=loadThing();
```

I know that's not right, but I'm not sure how to get the order correct to append to the child elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your insert method is correct, remove parentheses after your function and it will work,, here i mean

- `window.onload=loadThing();` Wrong
- `window.onload=loadThing;` Correct

Here you are assigning the result of your loadThing function which is `undefined` to your load event

Comment: Ahhhh, ok. Yep, removed the `()` from `window.onload=loadThing();` and sure enough that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just simply append child inside `.menu-footer` it will come after `p` tag element

e.g.

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.menu-footer');

var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.className = 'childDiv';
    newElement.innerText = 'Inner Div';
    parent.appendChild(newElement);
```

```html
<footer>
 <div class="menu-footer">
  <p>Stuff</p>
  <!-- want to insert HTML here -->
 </div>
</footer>
```

`